# sql LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE using PDO library doesn't update table xampp

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

I have table in mySql db where I want to upload csv file. I work with it on localhost XAMPP windows. When I enter this into PHPmyAdmin, then it works:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/10-xampp/htdocs/csvuploader/handling-fees.csv'
    INTO TABLE `dvtbl_getquotehc`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Table is updated.
But when I use this code in php file, then there is no error but table is still empty

```
try {

    Db::queryAll("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '?'
                INTO TABLE `dvtbl_getquotehc`
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES
                ",array('D:/10-xampp/htdocs/csvuploader/handling-fees.csv'));
} catch (PDOException $ex)
{
        echo 'PDO ERROR: '.$ex->getMessage();
}
```

What's wrong with PHP code?
DB class is just PDO wrapper library.

**EDIT 1**

Using mysqli helps and updating works. But still I don't know what's wrong with PDO style. Mysqli version below

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$changedrealpath."' REPLACE INTO TABLE dvtbl_getquotehc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES";

//Try to execute query (not stmt) and catch mysqli error from engine and php error
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->query($sql))) {
echo "\nQuery execute failed: ERRNO: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
};
```

**EDIT 2**

Problem is probably in prepared statements. When I use pdo->exec then it works. This code works for me:

```
$pdo->exec("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$fileName' REPLACE
    INTO TABLE `$hcTable` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
                    ");
} catch (PDOException $ex)
{
    echo 'PDO ERROR: '.$ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Does this query work if you place the filename directly into the query string, instead of parameterizing it?

Comment: No, same result 
calling QueryAll is preparing statement 
`public static function queryAll($query, $parameters = array()) {
  $statement = self::$connection->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute($parameters);
  return $statement->fetchAll();
 }`
@EatPeanutButter

Comment: Does [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) syntax improve the situation? You could use that to avoid escaping quotes etc.

Comment: I tried pdo->exec with direct query string and it works. @EatPeanutButter